# Rails 3 - cannot install rubber gem on Lion OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, rubygems, rvm

When I run

```
gem install rubber
```

I get

```
Fetching: highline-1.6.18.gem (100%)
Fetching: net-sftp-2.1.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: capistrano-2.15.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin directory.
```

I am not sure if using `sudo gem install rubber` is the right way to go...

Anyway, I made a little research about this error and using RVM could solve it.
I ran:

```
rvm -v
```

and got:

```
rvm 1.18.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

then I checked `rvm list` and got:

```
  ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p385 [ x86_64 ]
```

which means:

```
# =* - current && default
```

But despite I have installed the RVM, I am not sure if I am using it right, because I cannot install due the permission the **rubber** gem.

Is there something what I do overlook?

Thanks

Comment: Did you accidentally install a gem using `sudo gem install <xx>` earlier? If so, you may not have permission to the directory as a normal user anymore.

Comment: I am really not sure... Usually I install gems through `bundle` and now I run it through command line and got this error...

Answer (score 1):

Solved this way:

```
$GEM_HOME
=> -bash: /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385: is a directory
```

Then:

```
sudo chown -R radek /Users/adam/.rvm/gems
```

And finally:

```
gem install rubber
```